# Use of decline for condition has got worse

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am trying to say that health difficulties have got worse - or the difficulties have increased:

I have long term health difficulties that have declined and are significantly impacting on...

Does it make sense to use the word declined?

Comment: The difficulties have increased, not declined.

Comment: @tunny - his *condition* has declined; OP stated that his *difficulties have increased*.

Comment: Your *condition* can indeed decline, but if *difficulties decline*, it's like a double negation, meaning things got better. *His financial difficulties declined when he received a significant pay raise* means things got easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

*Declined* here implies something has got lower, so although you would probably be understood, it is not correct without some context to say what exactly is declining. For example, a common phrase is *his quality of life has declined*, which implies quality of life is being measured, and that the measure is lower. But a *health difficulty* is not something that clearly goes up or down - is a lower difficulty better or worse than a higher difficulty?

Instead consider a word that means 'got worse' rather than 'got lower', like [*deteriorated*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deteriorate):

> to make or become worse or lower in quality, value, character; to wear away or disintegrate (Collins English Dictionary)

Even then, the subject of the phrase is 'long term health difficulties', and it is still not clear if a difficulty deteriorating is going away or what. Consider *worsened* for clarity.

I think some options are:

1. I have chronic [medical] conditions which have *deteriorated*
2. I have long term health difficulties which have *worsened*
3. *Deterioration* in my health due to chronic medical conditions is significantly affecting...

Comment: Hi, Phil. While your answer is quite correct, some users will benefit from an added definition. It's good to support your answer, even when it appears obvious to you. Please feel free to roll back my edit if you feel it violates your answer in any way.